# Presigned URL generates an error - Nodejs AWS SDK S3

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am generating presigned S3 urls using the NodeJS AWS SDK. Here's my code

```
const s3 = new AWS.S3({accessKeyId: IAM_USER_KEY, secretAccessKey:IAM_USER_SECRET});

const myKey = 'test.csv';
const signedUrlExpireSeconds = 60 * 5;

const url = await s3.getSignedUrl('getObject', {
  Bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
  Key: myKey,
  Expires: signedUrlExpireSeconds,
})

console.log(url)
```

and when I access the url using the browser it shows this error

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>test.csv</Key>
<RequestId>EAFAC43D236CAFDF</RequestId>
<HostId>
knOGCpoUWq4TaRJmkx+ztWFliPOSABdnineRyNhhkqc/ahgPTpYSA+Aawmj5w2odWMt2kk3fGhY=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

In the client side it returns a 400 bad request error. Having a wrong bucket-name, key or secret key returns a different error for each one, so I don't think it's a typo problem but I don't know where the error is coming from.

Answer (score 3):

`NoSuchKey` is a 404 error, not 400.

The "key" here is the object key.

`<Key>test.csv</Key>`

There is no file *in the root of* this bucket named `test.csv`.  Object keys are case sensitive.

If you don't see the object in the S3 console, then that of course is the problem.

If the object appears in a folder in the console, that needs to be included in the key -- for the file `test.csv` inside folder `documents` the `Key` you need to use is `documents/test.csv`.

If you see this object in the console, examine the link in the console for special unprintable characters such as `%0A` (a newline) that you might have inadvertently included when you uploaded the object.

Comment: But I'm using this code to generate presigned urls, obviously there's no file in my bucket with that name, I'm just trying to create it

Comment: I switched the getObject to putObject, now I'm getting this error: The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.